# Why does my USB device randomly disconnects?

Tags: linux, usb, logs, pulseaudio, debugging

I am using Linux on a system that is constantly running. An USB Soundcard is connected to the system.

From time to time, on a random basis, sometimes in the middle of the night, the usb disconnects just to pop up again some seconds later.

```
Mär 18 03:52:41 test kernel: usb 1-1: USB disconnect, device number 35
 Mär 18 03:52:44 test kernel: usb 1-1: new full-speed USB device number 36 using xhci_hcd
 Mär 18 03:52:44 test kernel: usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=8087, idProduct=1024
 Mär 18 03:52:44 test kernel: usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
 Mär 18 03:52:44 test kernel: usb 1-1: Product: USB2.0 Device
 Mär 18 03:52:44 test kernel: usb 1-1: Manufacturer: Generic
 Mär 18 03:52:44 test kernel: usb 1-1: SerialNumber: 20170726905959
```

The main problem is, that sometimes rhe device, after several reconnects, does not come up again until I reboot.

This happens not just on one system, but on like 100 of them.

**My questions are:**

1. How to get an extended USB log from Linuxs USB stack? I would like to find out if there is maybe something like a suspend mode involved
2. Is it possible, that the usb controller, after a while, is blocking the device until rebooting? Any other ideas why device is in the end not coming up again?

Comment: Energy saving maybe? https://askubuntu.com/questions/185274/how-can-i-disable-usb-autosuspend-for-a-specific-device

Comment: That was my thought too, we are going to test it within the next days :) thanks for your answer!

Comment: Any progress? I think I have similar problem. TIA

Comment: It was simply a bad hardware decision in the end